# Android Studio Preview Not Showing RecyclerView and Toolbar Correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-studio-3.0

Please find the screenshots [image: screenshot]
I searched lot for this. My android studio is updated with 3.0.1.
Here are the dependencies in my project. Is the issue with studio 3.0.1?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'`
```

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change the theme and refresh layout.

Comment: @HemantParmar almost all themes applied nothing work for me?

Comment: share your xml file

Comment: change lib version `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'`

Comment: share your xml.

Comment: wait for a moment sharing.

Comment: @HemantParmar share the xml created the new xml stil the same result

Comment: what is your target sdk version ?

Comment: this view you shared is showing in android studio's xml design screen right ?

Comment: @Umair yes  target sdk is 23

Comment: you can find the error in red circle with exclamation point in top right corner of designer. pls share your failure error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If resolution Strategy  is present in your build.gradle file then please add updated dependency as below

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
        }
    }
```

Comment: you made my day whole day i am changing dependency in dependencies block in build gradle thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

In android Studio ,Go to File->Project Structure->Dependencies
Then click on green + sign and choose library dependencies.
There you can search recyclerview and include that dependency,
Build your project again
Hope this Helps

Comment: for recycle already added the latest dependecies of appcompact so this not works

Answer (score 1):

you need to update libraries to last(nearly last) versions:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

and change your compileSdkVersion to 27(nearly last version)

Comment: Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView Copy stack to clipboard   here is the exception

Answer (score 1):

Add these dependencies in your build.gradle file (Not in project level gradle).

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: In the preview section is there any error showing on top right corner.?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView

Comment: - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView 
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView