# RecyclerView of design 28.0.0 not showing in preview of android studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I started a project where I was using Android Studio 3.1.2 with 27.1.1 support libraries
I decided to upgrade my app so that it targets API 28 (Android P). For that I updated Android Studio, from version 3.1.2 to version 3.4.1 (the most recent), my gradle to version 3.4.2, (gradle 5) and the support libraries from version 27.1.1 to version 28.0.0

The problem I have is that the recyclerview that was in my project (version 28.0.0 now) is no longer displayed in the Android Studio preview. 
When I create a new Android project, the recyclerview 28.0.0. are displayed. The recyclerview has a display problem only in my old project.
I saw in the forums, it was advisable to downgrade from 28.0.0. to 27.x.x but it would force me to downgrade the target SDK version from 28 to 27, which I don't want.

Please someone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: What is your exact question ?do you want to use recyclerview with latest version of gradle and api ? 
if yes Than you can use  in dependencies{  api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'} 
and in xml like androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: Yes
But i don't want to use android x

Comment: small tip, ignore the preview... it's not very reliable, just use it as a reference. To answer your question, no do not downgrade, in fact i suggest you move even out of the support library and use the AndroiX module now since everything new is pushed there now

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to use Android X

Comment: This may help you..
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637586/android-studio-preview-not-showing-recyclerview-and-toolbar-correctly>?

Comment: @neha i have already seen this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things you can do

1) Recommended - Upgrade every thing to androidx and use sdk version 29 . Only 1 button click can migrate your project to androidx (Take a backup before migrating)

2)Downgrade to 27 which will be stable (not recommended)

3) try using alpha/beta/rc versions of support library 28 (may or maynot fix the issue)

Comment: So how should i do to migrate to Android X. How can i find this button ?

Comment: On top menu click on refactor -> Migrate to androidx

Comment: I migrated to android x. Issue is fixed. Thanks